# How to make fluid grid round up heights

Tags: jquery, html, css, less, jquery-isotope

I’m using isotope to create a grid like the one you see in the image. There is an underlying grid of 6 columns and all thumbnails a combination of squares (2x1, 2x2, 2x3, etc).

The way I’m sizing these thumbnails is by giving them a percentage `width` (something like 33.33%) and a percentage `padding-top`. So for instance `width 33.33%`, `padding-top 33.33%` makes a 2x2 thumbnail.

The problem I’m having is that percentage heights don’t always add up to the same number of pixels and therefore sometimes a 1px horizontal line is added between the thumbnails. For example two 2x1 blocks have a different height (by 1px) than a 2x2 thumbnails, as seen on the image attached.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? The live site is http://montenegrostudio.com/work

Comment: You're objective here is to remove that `1px white space` on certain parts of the `.grid-item.twocol_w` item classes?

Comment: Yes. My objective is to remove that 1px white space everywhere on the page the `.grid-item.twocol_w` class is one instance of it, but there are other combinations of heights that have the same result

Comment: Is it applicable that you could set the `height` property of every `.grid-item` classes to `1px` (e.g  `.post-type-archive-work #main #content .grid .grid-item {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1px;
}`

Comment: That's interesting. It works if applied after the page loads, but not if I add those properties to the CSS file. I guess I could apply them with JS after the page load...

Comment: Alright then. Glad we could help